# Calling dynamically created dictionaries

Tags: python

In my code i have created multiple dictionaries with the following code;

```
g = globals()
    lrange = len(requestcells * 2)
    for i in range(1, lrange):
        g['request_{0}'.format(i)] = {}
```

I then have a for loop which iterates over excel coordinates from a list and extracts data from them. Each row in the excel file is a separate set of data (request). I want to store these requests in separate dictionary.

request_1 request_2 etc etc (Dynamic as it always changes)

However I am stuck on how I can input the data into a new dictionary when its a new row and over multiple iterations.

```
for items in requestcells:
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=items, max_row=items):
            for cell in row:
                cell_location = (cell.column)    
                header_text = header_dict[cell_location + "3"]

                # This should be request 1 on first iteration and 3rd on second iteration

                request_??[header_text] = cell.value

        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=items + 1, max_row=items + 1):
            for cell in row:
                cell_location = (cell.column)    
                header_text = header_dict[cell_location + "3"]

                # This should be request 2 on first iteration and 4th on second iteration

                request_??[header_text] = cell.value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use variable names as part of your data structure. Variable names are for the programmer to type in. If you're using code to produce them, you probably want that code to be indexing a list or a dictionary instead.

I'd change the code you've shown to put the dictionaries in a list instead of making them each global variables. It might also make sense to use two separate lists for the two different sets of data you're currently interleaving with your even and odd request numbers.

```
requests = [{} for _ in range(len(requestcells * 2)]

for i, items in enumerate(requestcells):
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=items, max_row=items):
        for cell in row:
            cell_location = (cell.column)    
            header_text = header_dict[cell_location + "3"]

            requests[2*i][header_text] = cell.value

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=items + 1, max_row=items + 1):
        for cell in row:
            cell_location = (cell.column)    
            header_text = header_dict[cell_location + "3"]

            requests[2*i+1][header_text] = cell.value
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I had to make a few changes to it but you lead me on the right path! All working now (2x lists and adjusted code to no longer need * and can call based on len + list now. Thank you :)